# Show that the group contains an element of order 4

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given that a finite group $G$ has a commutator subgroup with order $2$, show that the index of the commutator subgroup is even.

The hint for this problem told me to show that the commutator subgroup is contained in the center, which I have proved using the fact that the conjugate of a commutator must also be a commutator.

The hint then said to find an element of order $4$, which is where I'm stuck. I assume it needs to use the fact that the commutator belongs to the center, but I'm unsure how.

Comment: Where did you find this exercise?

Comment: @Shaun https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Exercises_in_Group_Theory/6ZnfBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0 this book, in the chapter about commutators

Comment: It seems easier to prove first that $|G:G'|$ is even and then to prove that $G$ has an element of order four.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G'=\langle z\rangle$, so $z$ has order $2$. Let $g,h\in G$ such that $[g,h]=z$. As you have noted, $z$ is central.

One can then check that $g^h$ (the conjugate of $g$ by $h$) commutes with $g^{-1}$.

Now, if $g^n=1$, then

$$\begin{align}
z^n&=[g,h]^n\\
&=(g^{-1}g^h)^n\\
&=g^{-n}(g^h)^n\\
&=1.
\end{align}$$

But $z$ has order $2$, so $g$ must have even order. It it has order divisible by $4$, then you are done. So you can assume it has order $2x$, for $x$ odd. A little calculation shows that $[g^x,h]=z^x=z$, so we can replace $g$ by $g^x$, which has order $2$. Similarly for $h$. So now we can assume that $g$ and $h$ have order $2$.
But now, $(gh)^2=g^2h^2z=z$, so $gh$ has order $4$.

Comment: Ohh this makes sense. Now I see the significance of G' being contained in the center, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033907/if-the-commutator-of-a-finite-group-has-order-2-then-the-order-of-the-group-i) and its answer, $G$ contains a nonabelian group of order $8$. Up to isomorphism there are only two such groups and they all contain an element of order $4$.